# Can not figure out how to store $rootScope in angular.bootstrap

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to call a web service in AngularJS bootstrap method such that when my controller is finally executed, it has the necessary information to bring up the correct page.  The problem with the code below is that of course $rootScope is not defined in my $http.post(..).then(...

My response is coming back with the data I want and the MultiHome Controller would work if $rootScope were set at the point.  How can I access $rootScope in my angular document ready method or is there a better way to do this?

```
 angular.module('baseApp')
        .controller('MultihomeController', MultihomeController);

    function MultihomeController($state, $rootScope) {


        if ($rootScope.codeCampType === 'svcc') {
            $state.transitionTo('svcc.home');
        } else if ($rootScope.codeCampType === 'conf') {
            $state.transitionTo('conf.home');
        } else if ($rootScope.codeCampType === 'angu') {
            $state.transitionTo('angu.home');
        }
    }

    MultihomeController.$inject = ['$state', '$rootScope'];

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {

        var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
        var $http = initInjector.get("$http");
        $http.post('/rpc/Account/IsLoggedIn').then(function (response) {

            $rootScope.codeCampType = response.data

            angular.bootstrap(document, ['baseApp']);
        }, function (errorResponse) {
            // Handle error case
        });


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope (and $rootScope for that matter) is suppose to act as the glue between your controllers and views. I wouldn't use it to store application type information such as user, identity or security. For that I'd use the [constant](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant) method or a [factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services) (if you need to encapsulate more logic).

Example using constant:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','user',
function ($scope, user) {
    $scope.user = user;
}]);

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    var user = {};
    user.codeCampType = "svcc";
    app.constant('user', user);
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);    
});
```

**Note** Because we're bootstrapping the app, you'll need to get rid of the ng-app directive on your view.

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reimavronicolas/bm5147hq/)

Answer (score 0):

You could set it in a `run()` block that will get executed during bootstrapping:

```
baseApp.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.codeCampType = response.data;
});
angular.bootstrap(document, ['baseApp']);
```

I don't think you can use the injector because the scope isn't created before bootstrapping.  A `config()` block might work as well that would let you inject the data where you needed it.